# ASP.NET MVC pass parameter as part of url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, routes

I'm trying to create well looking urls in my application, but when I'm using following construction

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Account", new { userId = user.Id })
```

I've got next reference `mysite.com/Account/Edit?userId=42`.

How to get an url which looks like `mysite.com/Account/Edit/42`?

Comment: change `userId` to `id` then it'll hit your default route of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project under the `App_Start` folder you'll have a file named `RouteConfig.cs` this is where you can specify custom routing for your application.

By default you will have the following

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Which will be hit if you did something like `Url.Action("Edit", "Account", new {id = user.Id})`

If you want to accomodate for your rule where you don't want to change `userId` to `id` then you can create one as follows:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "EditRule",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{userId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Edit", action = "Account", userId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**NOTE:** the custom rule should appear before your default rule otherwise the default rule will be hit

Answer (score 1):

Use

> `@Url.Action("Edit", "Account", new { Id = user.Id })`

and also change `userId` to `Id` if you have used it in your `**controller method**` and `**model logic**`

`